# Checking room availability in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

The relational database schema I created for my hotel reservation system has 4 tables:

Customer Table -

```
CustomerID (PK) 
title
firstname
surname
address 
town
county 
country 
postcode 
tel
email 
username
password
```

Room Table

```
RoomID (PK)
RoomType
Description
PricePerNight
```

Reservation

```
ReservationID (PK)
CustomerID (FK)
RoomID (FK)
ArrivalDate
DepartureDate
```

Room_Availability

```
RoomID(PK/FK)
Availability
```

In the front end I have two ajax calendars, allowing a user to select an arrival and a departure date, with a check availability button beside it.

I am unsure how I would go about searching the database to check which rooms are available and then display them on the next page in like a gridview or something.

Also, is my database schema correct, can someone assist me on that?

Comment: Please read [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Welcome to SO, unfortunately your question needs to be about a specific programming problem you are having. You are asking for design analysis and suggestions, which makes your question far too broad. Try narrowing it down.

Comment: 1 - Your DB schema does not support your functionality. 2 - This is my opinion. 3 - no one said that data must be stored in such way so that querying should be easy. 4 - hotel system is a good example of a system that should have normalized and denormalized data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gitsitgo says, your question is too broad to answer fully.  But let's pare it down a bit.  First, I'm assuming that a room can be unavailable for two reasons: one is that it's being repaired or something, and two is that it's already reserved.  If so, your schema looks ok.

So, to check availability, you need to take the beginning and end dates the user provides, and find all the rooms that are both available and aren't reserved for any day that is between the two dates the user provides.

The logic to do this is to select all the room ids that do not meet any of these criteria:

1. Start date is between reservation start date and reservation end date, inclusive.
2. End date is between reservation start date and reservation end date, inclusive.
3. Start date is less than reservation start date and end date is greater than reservation end date.
4. Room id is marked as unavailable in the availability table.

To accomplish this, look up and apply EXISTS or IN.  (You'll want to look up BETWEEN as well.)  Forget about displaying it in a grid until you figure out what to display.

Comment: Then add another WHERE clause (use AND) that says that the RoomType is the one selected.